# Use a parameter multiple times in hydra config file

Tags: python, fb-hydra

I am currently trying to replace the usage of argparse with hydra files to set the hyperparameters of a deep learning neural network.

I succeeded in using a config.yaml file linked to a hydra main file to run a training and a prediction.

However, I am loading three .py files for the process and there are some common parameters between them (file path, number of labels for example).

Is there a way of using a parameter several times in a config.yaml file supported by hydra ?

Main file structure:

```
import time
from omegaconf import DictConfig, OmegaConf
from segmentation_monai import split, train, predict
import hydra
import warnings
from segmentation_monai import split
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=UserWarning)

@hydra.main(config_path='.', config_name="config_bis")

def my_param(cfg:DictConfig) -> None:

    if cfg.split.run: split.main(cfg.split)
    if cfg.train.run: train.main(cfg.train)
    if cfg.predict.run: predict.main(cfg.predict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_param()
```

Config file:

```
split:
  run: False
#  mandatory:
  root_path: D:/breast_seg/db_test
  data_dim: 3
  train_dim: 3
  [...]

train:
  run: False
# mandatory:
  root_path: D:/breast_seg/db_test
  data_dim: 3
  train_dim: 3
  [...]

predict:
  run: True
# mandatory:
  root_path: D:/breast_seg/db_test
  data_dim: 3
  train_dim: 3
  [...]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same parameter multiple in the config using [OmegaConf interpolations](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/usage.html#variable-interpolation).

```yaml
# Extracting to an individual config node. 
# You can also reuse one of your own nodes for this.
data:
  room_path: D:/breast_seg/db_test
  data_dim: 3
  train_dim: 3

split:
  run: False
#  mandatory:
  root_path: ${data.root_path}
  data_dim: ${data.data_dim}
  train_dim: ${data.train_dim}
  [...]

train:
  run: False
# mandatory:
  root_path: ${data.root_path}
  data_dim: ${data.data_dim}
  train_dim: ${data.train_dim}
  [...]

predict:
  run: True
# mandatory:
  root_path: ${data.root_path}
  data_dim: ${data.data_dim}
  train_dim: ${data.train_dim}
  [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer violates DRY in a significant manner.

Add a single parameter to the common data set and all three locations must likewise have edits.

(I'm learning Hydra myself... for a strange reason, I've struggled in getting it, but working through this has helped...)

The OP question: *Is there a way of using a parameter several times in a config.yaml file supported by hydra ?*

Hydra can easily solve this issue, in a very clean manner in first example. Second will show how it can be expanded to have different params for each of the `split`, `train`, and `predict`.

**Primary Example**

The below was derived from details found at [Hydra Overriding Packages Doc](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/overriding_packages/)

First let's look at the output:

```
cfg:
------------
split:
  params:
    root_path: D:/breast_seg/db_test
    data_dim: 3
    train_dim: 3
  run: true
train:
  params:
    root_path: D:/breast_seg/db_test
    data_dim: 3
    train_dim: 3
  run: false
predict:
  params:
    root_path: D:/breast_seg/db_test
    data_dim: 3
    train_dim: 3
  run: false

split.main:
------------
root_path: D:/breast_seg/db_test
data_dim: 3
train_dim: 3
```

This shows that each of the three config sets (`split`, `train`, `predict`) are receiving the common data params.

Note that the common data, and in the custom params in the next example, are all held under the `params` key. This enables the param, `run`, to be simply used as a switch to invoke said functionality, e.g. `cfg.split.run`, and the actual params for the functionality is only passed, e.g. `cfg.split.params`.

The code which produced the above:

```
# ----- myapp.py
import time
from omegaconf import DictConfig, OmegaConf
import hydra

config_name = 'config_with_base_plus_custom.yaml'   # secondary example
config_name = 'config.yaml'                         # primary example

@hydra.main(version_base='1.2', config_path='conf', config_name=config_name )
def my_param( cfg : DictConfig ) -> None:

    resolve = True

    print(f'cfg:\n------------\n{OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg)}\n')

    if cfg.split.run:   print(f'split.main:\n------------\n{OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg.split.params)}')
    if cfg.train.run:   print(f'train.main:\n------------\n{OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg.train.params)}')
    if cfg.predict.run: print(f'predict.main:\n------------\n{OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg.predict.params)}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_param()
```

Directory structure and yaml files:

```
|- myapp.py
|- conf
   |- config.yaml
   |- params
      |- common.yaml
```

The `@split.params` places the config found in `params/common.yaml` in package `split.params`. Likewise for the other two key sets. See the reference Hydra doc.

```
# ----- config.yaml
defaults:
    - params@split.params   : common
    - params@train.params   : common
    - params@predict.params : common
    - _self_

split:
    run: True

train:
    run: False

predict:
    run: False
```

```
# ----- common.yaml
root_path: 'D:/breast_seg/db_test'
data_dim: 3
train_dim: 3
```

This is really clean and DRY.

Need another common param? Simply place it in `common.yaml` and it will be populated in appropriate locations.

**Secondary Extended Example**

Now let's assume that one wants to have extended params for `split` that are basic and also able to extend.

In the `myapp.py`, swap the two `config_name` lines.

Extend the directory structure and add two yaml files:

```
|- myapp.py
|- conf
   |- config.yaml
   |- config_with_base_plus_custom.yaml
   |- params
      |- common.yaml
      |- split_base.yaml
      |- split_custom.yaml
```

The `config.yaml` is unused, it is from prior example.

The `common.yaml` is **used** and remains unchanged.

The other three files are as follows:

```
# ----- config_with_base_plus_custom.yaml (an expansion of original config.yaml)
defaults:
    - params@split.params   : common
    - params@train.params   : common
    - params@predict.params : common
    - override params@split.params   : split_custom
    - _self_

split:
    run: True

train:
    run: False

predict:
    run: False
```

```
# ----- split_base
split_paramA: 'localhost'
split_paramB: 'base paramB'
split_paramC: ???
split_paramD: 'base paramD'
```

```
# ----- split_custom.yaml
defaults:
    - split_base
    - common

split_paramC: 'fills in required paramC'
split_paramD: 'custom paramD overrides base paramD'
split_paramE: 'unique to split custom'
```

The output is as follows:

```
cfg:
------------
split:
  params:
    split_paramA: localhost
    split_paramB: base paramB
    split_paramC: fills in required paramC
    split_paramD: custom paramD overrides base paramD
    root_path: D:/breast_seg/db_test
    data_dim: 3
    train_dim: 3
    split_paramE: unique to split custom
  run: true
train:
  params:
    root_path: D:/breast_seg/db_test
    data_dim: 3
    train_dim: 3
  run: false
predict:
  params:
    root_path: D:/breast_seg/db_test
    data_dim: 3
    train_dim: 3
  run: false


split.main:
------------
split_paramA: localhost
split_paramB: base paramB
split_paramC: fills in required paramC
split_paramD: custom paramD overrides base paramD
root_path: D:/breast_seg/db_test
data_dim: 3
train_dim: 3
split_paramE: unique to split custom
```

So several things to note:

- The `split` key continues to have the same common data as the other two keys.
- The `split` key gets additional params.
- Those params are in a base, which also has a delayed, to be filled in later (???) key-value.
- The params come from both the base and the custom.
- `split_paramA` and `split_paramB` is only in the base.
- `split_paramC` is filled in by custom.
- `split_paramD` which occurs in both base and custom, is overridden by the custom.
- `split_paramE` is only in the custom, not in base.

Personally I think that Hydra provides an excellent, elegant solution, once one can figure it out - its taken me a bit... and still learning.

..Otto